# Installing OpenCV 2.4.7 in windows 7 x64

Tags: c++, opencv

I have problem with installing **OpenCV 2.4.7** on Windows 7 x64. What I did so far:

1. I have downloaded opencv from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/).
2. My opencv folder's destination is: **D:\installed\opencv**
3. Opened command line and wrote this **setx -m OPENCV_DIR D:\installed\opencv\build\x64\vc10** it was succesfull
4. Opened my favourite c++ editor DevCPP and wrote this code to test:

   > ```
   > #include <iostream>
   > using namespace std;
   >
   > #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
   > using namespace cv;
   >
   > int main()
   > {
   >   system("PAUSE");
   >   return 0;
   > }
   > ```

But it gives me this error:

> C:\Users\torayeff\Desktop\test.cpp C:\Users\torayeff\Desktop\C
>   opencv2/core/core.hpp:  No such file or directory.

What should I do? I just want to try sample codes from OpenCV.

Comment: Could try using `#include "opencv/cv.h"` and see if it works..? I hope your include directory is set, though.

Comment: DevCPP is old and bugged. Switch to a new IDE/compiler

Comment: @llnk what would you recommend instead?

Comment: @scap3y the sameproblem

Comment: @torayeff [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2) is free ...

Comment: I have been using VS Ultimate for a long time now (since switching from Netbeans) and it hasn't been giving me issues. Maybe you could try the express edition and see how it works..?